# Android mysql connection issue

Tags: android

I am trying to create a simple android app which connects with mysql using php. I tried the login tutorial posted in [this site](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/). Please help.

My codes are:

- LoginScreen

---

```
package com.project.test;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.R.integer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestingInstanceExpenseActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private Button login;
    private Button newUser;
    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_login);
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        newUser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_newuser);

        // Login button Click Event
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String uname = username.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();

                Log.d("Button", "Login");
                JSONObject jsonObject = userFunctions.loginUser(uname, pass);
                Log.i("loginuser","called login user function" );
                /*try {
                    JSONArray  x = jsonObject.getJSONArray("success");
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }*/
                try {
                    if(!(jsonObject.getString(KEY_SUCCESS).equals(null))) {
                        String res = jsonObject.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Valid Credential", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Credential", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        newUser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Createuser.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- UserFunctions

---

```
package com.project.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;

    private static String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/instance_expense_calculator/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    public JSONObject loginUser(String username, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        Log.i("JSON Parser class", "json class method invoked");
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String firstname, String lastname, String username, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", firstname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", lastname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

}
```

- JSONParser

---

```
package com.project.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                 jObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 Log.i("testing", jObj.getString("tag"));
                 Log.i("testing", jObj.getString("success"));
                 Log.i("testing", jObj.getString("error"));
             }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

My php files are:

- index.php

---

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['tag'])){
    //get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];
    //include db handler
    require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    //response Array
    $response = array('tag' => $tag, 'success' => 0, 'error' => 0);
    //check for tag type
    if($tag == 'login') {
        //request type is check login
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        //check for user
        $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($username, $password);

        if($user) {
            //user found
            //echo json with success = 1
            $response['success'] = 1;
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            //user not found
            //echo jason with error = 1
            $response['error'] = 1;
            $response['error_msg'] = "Incorrect email or password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else if ($tag == 'register') {
        //request type is register new user
        $name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $name = $_POST['lasst_name'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        //check if user already exists

        if($db-> isUserExisted($username)){
            //user exist - error responbse
            $response['error'] = 2;
            $response['error_msg'] = "User already existed";
            echo json_encode($response);

        } else {
            //store user information
            $user = $db->storeUser($first_name, $last_name, $username, $password);

            if($user) {
                //stored successfully
                $response['success'] = 1;
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                //user failed to store
                $response['error'] = 1;
                $response['error_msg'] = "Error occured while Registring the user";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Request";
    }
} else {
    echo "Access Denied";
}
?>
```

- DB_Functions.php

---

```
<?php
    class DB_Functions {
        private $db;
        //put code here
        //constructor
        function construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        //connecting to database
        $this ->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this ->db->connect();
    }
    //destructor
    /**
    *storing new user
    *returns user details
    */
    public function storeUser($username, $first_name, $last_name, $password) {
        mysql_query("Insert into user_registration values ('$username', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$password')");
    }
    /**
    *Get user by email and password
    */
    public function getUserInformation($username, $password) {
        $result = mysql_query("Select * from user_registration where username = '$username' and password = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());
        //check for result
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($no_of_rows > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }
    /**
    *check user is existed or not
    */
    public function isUserExisted($username) {
        $result = mysql_query("Select username from users where username = '$username'");
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($no_of_rows >0 ) {
            //user existed
            return true;
        } else {
            //user not existed
            return false;
        }
    }
    /** 
    *Encrypting password
    *@param password
    * returns salt and encrypted password
    */
}
?>
```

---

- DB_Connect.php

  - config.php

Mysql database contains the table user_registration with fields first_name, last_name, username and password.

The error receiving:

```
03-05 16:39:00.589: D/Button(827): Login
03-05 16:39:00.589: I/JSON Parser class(827): json class method invoked
03-05 16:39:00.908: E/JSON(827): <br />
03-05 16:39:00.908: E/JSON(827): <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
03-05 16:39:00.908: E/JSON(827): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_Functions::getUserByEmailAndPassword() in C:\wamp\www\instance_expense_calculator\index.php on line <i>16</i></th></tr>
03-05 16:39:00.908: E/JSON(827): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
03-05 16:39:00.908: E/JSON(827): <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
03-05 16:39:00.908: E/JSON(827): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0011</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>377960</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\instance_expense_calculator\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
03-05 16:39:00.908: E/JSON(827): </table></font>
03-05 16:39:00.908: W/System.err(827): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
03-05 16:39:00.908: W/System.err(827):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
03-05 16:39:00.919: W/System.err(827):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
03-05 16:39:00.919: W/System.err(827):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
03-05 16:39:00.919: W/System.err(827):  at com.project.test.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:70)
03-05 16:39:00.919: W/System.err(827):  at com.project.test.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:34)
03-05 16:39:00.919: W/System.err(827):  at com.project.test.TestingInstanceExpenseActivity$1.onClick(TestingInstanceExpenseActivity.java:53)
03-05 16:39:00.919: W/System.err(827):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-05 16:39:00.919: W/System.err(827):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-05 16:39:00.919: W/System.err(827):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-05 16:39:00.929: W/System.err(827):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-05 16:39:00.929: W/System.err(827):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-05 16:39:00.929: W/System.err(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-05 16:39:00.929: W/System.err(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 16:39:00.929: W/System.err(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-05 16:39:00.929: W/System.err(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-05 16:39:00.929: W/System.err(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-05 16:39:00.929: W/System.err(827):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 16:39:00.929: I/loginuser(827): called login user function
03-05 16:39:00.939: D/AndroidRuntime(827): Shutting down VM
03-05 16:39:00.939: W/dalvikvm(827): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.project.test.TestingInstanceExpenseActivity$1.onClick(TestingInstanceExpenseActivity.java:62)
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-05 16:39:00.949: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 16:39:10.488: I/Process(827): Sending signal. PID: 827 SIG: 9
```

Comment: This question is has too much code and no enough explanation of what is going wrong. You have already spent time trying to asses the situation, don't force us to spend that same amount of time just to get to where you are now. You should also edit the question so that code is block formatted.

Answer (score 3):

You have no function named getUserByEmailAndPassword() in DB_functions, yet you call it in index.php.

Then there is an issue in JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl() - you might want to check the contents of the "json" variable - which will not be a valid JSON array.

Answer (score 2):

your url is not sending JSON data. Check with your server side implementation. try printing log to know the data you are receiving from server.

Hope this will help you.